# buildroot how to skip downloading step

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded-linux, wget, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot to add a python package `python-xxx`, but it always show `time out` or `404 error`,

```
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:189: /home/buildroot/output/build/python-xxx/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
```

so I downloaded the package `python-xxx.tar.gz` somewhere else and put it in the `buildroot/dl/python-xxx` directory to skip the downloading step.

Then I try `make`, but it always starts from downloading step again, how to avoid the downloading and goes to `extracting` and following steps?

Can I get some help, pls?

Answer (score 2):

You're not giving enough details to really help you. However, if you put the source code tarball in $(DL_DIR) with the correct name, Buildroot will definitely skip the download step and use this tarball.

If you want more help, provide more details, such as the .mk file of the package you're creating, as well as the complete build log of that package, not just the last line which does not carry any useful information.